# override log4j.properties in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, log4j

How do I override the default log4j.properties in hadoop? If I set the hadoop.root.logger=WARN,console, it doesnot print the logs on the console, whereas what I want is that it shouldn't print the INFO in the logs file. I added a log4j.properties file in my jar, but I am unable to override the default one. In short, I want the log file to print only the errors and warnings.

```
# Define some default values that can be overridden by system properties
hadoop.root.logger=INFO,console
hadoop.log.dir=.
hadoop.log.file=hadoop.log

#
# Job Summary Appender 
#
# Use following logger to send summary to separate file defined by 
# hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file rolled daily:
# hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger=INFO,JSA
# 
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger=${hadoop.root.logger}
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file=hadoop-mapreduce.jobsummary.log

# Define the root logger to the system property "hadoop.root.logger".
log4j.rootLogger=${hadoop.root.logger}, EventCounter

# Logging Threshold
log4j.threshold=ALL

#
# Daily Rolling File Appender
#

log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}

# Rollver at midnight
log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

# 30-day backup
#log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=30
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern format: Date LogLevel LoggerName LogMessage
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
# Debugging Pattern format
#log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n


#
# console
# Add "console" to rootlogger above if you want to use this 
#

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n

#
# TaskLog Appender
#

#Default values
hadoop.tasklog.taskid=null
hadoop.tasklog.iscleanup=false
hadoop.tasklog.noKeepSplits=4
hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=100
hadoop.tasklog.purgeLogSplits=true
hadoop.tasklog.logsRetainHours=12

log4j.appender.TLA=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogAppender
log4j.appender.TLA.taskId=${hadoop.tasklog.taskid}
log4j.appender.TLA.isCleanup=${hadoop.tasklog.iscleanup}
log4j.appender.TLA.totalLogFileSize=${hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize}

log4j.appender.TLA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.TLA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n

#
#Security appender
#
hadoop.security.log.file=SecurityAuth.audit
log4j.appender.DRFAS=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.DRFAS.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.security.log.file}

log4j.appender.DRFAS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DRFAS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
#new logger
# Define some default values that can be overridden by system properties
hadoop.security.logger=INFO,console
log4j.category.SecurityLogger=${hadoop.security.logger}

#
# Rolling File Appender
#

#log4j.appender.RFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.RFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}

# Logfile size and and 30-day backups
#log4j.appender.RFA.MaxFileSize=1MB
#log4j.appender.RFA.MaxBackupIndex=30

#log4j.appender.RFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} - %m%n
#log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n

#
# FSNamesystem Audit logging
# All audit events are logged at INFO level
#
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=WARN

# Custom Logging levels

#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=DEBUG

# Jets3t library
log4j.logger.org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service=ERROR

#
# Event Counter Appender
# Sends counts of logging messages at different severity levels to Hadoop Metrics.
#
log4j.appender.EventCounter=org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.EventCounter

#
# Job Summary Appender
#
log4j.appender.JSA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.JSA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file}
log4j.appender.JSA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.JSA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.appender.JSA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress$JobSummary=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress$JobSummary=false

#
# MapReduce Audit Log Appender
#

# Set the MapReduce audit log filename
#hadoop.mapreduce.audit.log.file=hadoop-mapreduce.audit.log

# Appender for AuditLogger.
# Requires the following system properties to be set
#    - hadoop.log.dir (Hadoop Log directory)
#    - hadoop.mapreduce.audit.log.file (MapReduce audit log filename)

#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.AuditLogger=INFO,MRAUDIT
#log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.AuditLogger=false
#log4j.appender.MRAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.mapreduce.audit.log.file}
#log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
#log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
```

Comment: please post the complete log4j.properties file from hadoop. You have to change the filelogger not the root logger.

Comment: Here is the [log4j.properties](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.22/common/conf/log4j.properties) file.

Comment: I wouldnt want to change the default file, as I want to custom the logs only for one user. so, how should I go about doing that?

Comment: Which jar was the log4j.properties added? Keeping it in the classpath should be enough for both the client and the nodes.

Comment: I packed it with my map-reduce code. How do i tell Hadoop to use it from my jar and not the default one.

Answer (score 8):

Modify the `log4j` file inside `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`. Note that hadoop job wont consider the log4j file of your application. It will consider the one inside `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`.

If you want to force hadoop to use some other `log4j` file, try one of these:

1. You can try what @Patrice said. ie.

   -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/user_specific/log4j.xml
2. Customize HADOOP_CONF_DIR/log4j.xml and set the logger level for "your" classes as per your wish. Other user(s) wont be affected due to this unless both are having classes with same package structure. This wont work for core hadoop classes as all users will get afftected.
3. Create your customized log4j file. Replicate the directory HADOOP_CONF_DIR and put your log4j file inside it. export HADOOP_CONF_DIR to your conf directory. Other users will point to the default one.

Answer (score 8):

If you use the default Log4j.properties file the logging settings get overridden by environment variables from the startup script. If you want to use the default log4j and just simply want to change the logging level, use `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/hadoop-env.sh`

For example, to change your logger to DEBUG log level and DRFA logger, use

```
export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER="DEBUG,DRFA"
```

Answer (score 6):

1. You could remove the `log4j.properties` from your `hadoop jar`
2. OR make sure that your `jar`/`log4j.properties` is first in the classpath (log4j picks the first `log4j.properties` from the classpath that it finds)
3. OR specify the system variable: `-Dlog4j.configuration=PATH_TO_FILE`

See the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) to learn how log4j finds the configuration.

Comment: I tried by specifying the system variable. I changed the foll two statements:
**hadoop.root.logger=WARN,console  

hadoop.security.logger=WARN,console**
So, it shouldnt print info on the console but still it does. I cant find out what changes to make in the file logger. Also, how should i set log4j.properties in the classpath?

Comment: Also, I dont want the effect to be universal. It should be limited to a single user. So, it would be better if i pack it in my jar. Is there a way around?

Comment: @sid post the log4j.properties (edit your question), I am not aware of any logger that is limited to a singe user.

Comment: here is the log4j file [http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.22/common/conf/log4j.properties]

Comment: I packed the log4j file in the jar and set it in the class path with **-Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true**. I donot see any difference.

Comment: @sid sorry hadoop is not speciality, my answer refers to log4j only but should work in hadoop according to its rules

Answer (score 4):

I was faced with the same problem (CDH3U3, Hadoop 0.20.2). I finally found a solution with (note `file:` prefix in the path):

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/user_specific/log4j.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

**Maven Packaging:**

Once I realized I needed to add my custom `debug-log.properties` file to src/main/java/resources, Maven added it to the application.jar root directory and then it was just a matter of referring to it or not in `-Dlog4j.configuration=debug-log.properties` from the command line.

**Oozie `<java>` Action:**

In regard to Oozie, use `<java-opts>-Dlog4j.configuration=${log4jConfig}</java-opts>` in the workflow.xml actions and define the following in a job.properties file.

```
#one of the following log4j.config parameters must be defined 
#log4jConfig=log4j.properties
log4jConfig=debug-log.properties
```

**Oozie `<map-reduce>` Action:**

```
 <property>
      <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
      <value>-Dlog4j.configuration=${log4jConfig}</value>
 </property>
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Sulpha, 
for hadoop 1.2.1, it is important to override the task-log4j.properties that is present inside hadoop-core.jar

For my pseudo distributed mode,

I was unable to print the debug messages of my pig UDFs and had to delete the task-log4j.properties from  hadoop-core.jar and replace it with a copy of the $HADOOP_INSTALL/conf/log4j.properties.

Used the

```
zip -d hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar task-log4j.properties #to delete
```

and

```
zip -g hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar task-log4j.properties #to add back
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is already configured log4j properties file inside the jar file.  you can override by simple putting -Dlog4j.configuration= before the -classpath

here is the sample:

java -Dlog4j.configuration=..\conf\log4j.properties -classpath %CLASSPATH%

Answer (score 0):

Put log4j.configuration option *in* the child java options.

I.e.

```
hadoop jar ... -Dmapred.child.java.opts=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/...../log4j_debug.properties
```

You must put log4j_debug.properties file on all slave servers in a same directory path like /home/yourname/log4j_debug.properties or /tmp/log4j_debug.properties

This setting overwrites mapred.child.java.opts settings.
If you want to use with another options like -Xmx32m, which means 32MB heap size,  then do like following:

```
hadoop jar ... -Dmapred.child.java.opts='-Xmx32m -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/...../log4j_debug.properties'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Hadoop 1.2.1 there are 2 config files: log4j.properties and **task-log4j.properties**
So to make example above work the change have to be done in task-log4j.properties not in log4j.properties

you can add follwing line in your task-log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.org.xxx=WARN
```