# hdfs get fails on a particular client node

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a strange problem with HDFS. While get operations on an existant file work like a charm on all clients accessing a HDFS cluster, it fails on one client:

Working host:

```
[user@host1]$ hadoop fs -ls /path/to/file.csv
found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 compute supergroup       1628 2013-12-10 12:22 /path/to/file.csv
[user@host1]$ hadoop fs -get /path/to/file.csv /tmp/test.csv
[user@host1]$  cat /tmp/test.csv 
48991,24768,2013-12-10 00:00:00,1,0.0001,0.0001
```

Not working host:

```
[user@host2]$ hadoop fs -ls /path/to/file.csv
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 compute supergroup       1628 2013-12-10 12:22 /path/to/file.csv
[user@host2]$ hadoop fs -get /path/to/file.csv /tmp/test.csv
get: java.lang.NullPointerException
[user@host2]$  cat /tmp/test.csv 
cat: /tmp/test.csv: No such file or directory
```

Using a java hdfs client on working host:

```
[user@host1]$ java -jar hadoop_get-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar hdfs://my.namenode:port  /path/to/file.csv
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
48991,24768,2013-12-10 00:00:00,1,0.0001,0.0001
```

Using a java hdfs client on non working host:

```
[user@host2]$ java -jar hadoop_get-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar hdfs://my.namenode:port  /path/to/file.csv
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.lang.NullPointerException): java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1225)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:154)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:957)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:947)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:171)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:138)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSInputStream.java:131)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1104)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:246)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:711)
at my.namespace.client.Client.main(Client.java:34)
```

Comment: Have a look at [override log4j.properties in hadoop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081625/override-log4j-properties-in-hadoop)

Comment: What did you see, user1737246?!?  WHAT HAPPENED!?!?
We have the same problem. DNS not a factor.  We're able to WRITE files from all systems, only some have issues READING files.  They can read the directories fine, move files, etc.  Only Reading the files fail with java.lang.NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved for us by deploying client configurations, refreshing cluster, and restarting HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CDH4? We've got the same problem after upgrading from CDH3.

Try researching reverse DNS lookup name for the problem host - we'd found difference with problem host and hosts with no problems only in DNS resolving. After fixing it - all is ok.